# Restricting hosts in a user specific ssh config

Tags: ssh

I am trying to create a new config file in (user_home)/.ssh/ and setup some rules that would restrict only logins for one user on the system without changing the current /etc/ssh/sshd_conf file or use the 'from=""' line in the users public key.  I was able to get it to work by blocking logins from systems on DNS that have a registered hostname in DNS, but I am noticing that one system I am testing with that has an IP and is not in DNS, is still able to login with the public key.

Is there something that I am missing where I can allow only one hostname and/or IP in the users ssh config that will block that user from trying to log in from other locations other than the hostname and/or IP that is specified in the users ssh config?

I am hoping that someone can point out what I may be missing.  Here is the current config (after quite a bit of playing around):

```
Host (hostname)
        HostName (hostname)*
        ForwardAgent no
        ForwardX11 no
        ForwardX11Trusted no
        Port 1472
        Protocol 2
        ServerAliveInterval 60
        ServerAliveCountMax 30
        PasswordAuthentication no
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
        AllowUsers (user)
Host *
        HostName !(hostname)*
        AddressFamily any
        PasswordAuthentication no
        PubkeyAuthentication no
        DenyUsers *
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to create a new config file in ~/.ssh/ and setup some rules that would over ride the default system rules and restrict only logins for one user on the system.

As far as I know in a  `~/.ssh/config` you're setting up options and restrictions for the ssh client, which, while oftentimes very useful, are not restrictions enforced by the server.
That `~/.ssh/config` configuration file only governs how the ssh client for that user behaves and only then  for connections made *from* that system (not *to* that system) and as long as the client doesn't ignore them with  for instance `ssh -F /dev/null`  ...

To set up restrictions that will be enforced on the server, that a user can't circumvent or ignore, requires setting them in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. You can override defaults and relax or restrict them for specific connections  with a ["`Match`"](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) block:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#here go defaults for all connections/users
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no
...
# Use Match directives to override default settings and specify specific settings
# for users, groups, hosts 
# https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match
Match User hbruijn
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match Address 192.0.2.1 
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I may have to edit it since I think the question I asked originally was not very clear.

I see what you are proposing and thank you for pointing it out, however, the end result I am trying to achieve is that "user_a" can only log in with an ssh key from one host and not from any other hosts.  All other users can log in as normally defined in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

I know this is normally controlled by a "from=" line at the beginning of the pub key on the target host, but I ran into a situation where that is not an option I can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the allowed ssh client ip address within the `AllowUsers` option in form `username@ip`. This form also supports the wildcards in the address part (after `@` symbol).